# How to build a correct CA chain using cloudflare oigin certificates?

Tags: ssl, nginx, cloudflare, ca

## Use Case

this is my use case: I have a page available trough cloudflare (proxied), let's call it example.com.
I created a Origin Certificate with Cloudflare and linked it in my nginx config, works fine. Cloudflare works in "Full" SSL mode.
Now I want to be able to basically add `127.0.0.1   example.com` to my `/etc/hosts` so the server itself can directly access the page (it is not really an option to use a different domain with software running on this server to circumvent this).

Now obviously when I `curl -v https://example.com` I get a ssl error.

## What I did so far

So basically, did some research and learned about CA chains and so on.
I found the Cloudflare Origin root CA's ([Cloudflare Documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000479507#h_30cc332c-8f6e-42d8-9c59-6c1f06650639), Step 4) and included that in the cert chain in my nginx server (basically first the Cloudflare Origin cert they generated for me, then the Root CA). I also installed the Root CA to `/usr/share/ca-certificates` (and `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`) and ran `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates` and it was properly added to the `/etc/ssl/certs` dir. So far so good?

Result: Does not work.

## Further research

Stumbling upon this [guide](https://medium.com/@superseb/get-your-certificate-chain-right-4b117a9c0fce) I looked the following up:

- `cert.pem` is my Cloudflare issued certificate
- `ca.pem` is the cloudflare root CA (the ecc file)

```
root@host:~/ssltest# openssl verify cert.pem
O = "CloudFlare, Inc.", OU = CloudFlare Origin CA, CN = CloudFlare Origin Certificate
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error cert.pem: verification failed
root@host:~/ssltest# openssl x509 -noout -issuer -in cert.pem
issuer=C = US, O = "CloudFlare, Inc.", OU = CloudFlare Origin SSL Certificate Authority, L = San Francisco, ST = California
root@host:~/ssltest# openssl x509 -noout -issuer -in ca.pem
issuer=C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = "CloudFlare, Inc.", OU = CloudFlare Origin SSL ECC Certificate Authority
root@host:~/ssltest# openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem cert.pem
O = "CloudFlare, Inc.", OU = CloudFlare Origin CA, CN = CloudFlare Origin Certificate
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error cert.pem: verification failed
```

So basically the Issuer of `cert.pem` and Subject of `ca.pem` do not match up.
This means for me: Either there is an Intermediate Cert that I do not know how to get, or Cloudflare gave me a cert that is not from the root CA they gave me.

Also the difference between Issuer and Subject is super small:

- `CloudFlare Origin SSL Certificate Authority`
- `CloudFlare Origin SSL ECC Certificate Authority`

What can I do to fix it?
I'm probably just not seeing something here, can anyone help me out? Thank you!

Comment: "Also the difference between Issuer and Subject is super small:" It is binary. There is either a difference or there isn't. Quantifying it (it is small)  is irrelevant. As soon as there is a difference (even 1 bit, even just a whitespace), then you are looking at two different things (different certificates). Also even if it is exactly the same, it may still be different certificates in fact.

Comment: Cloudflare servers different certificates (elliptic curve based or RSA based) to clients depending what clients put in `ClientHello` record, in order to try the highest possible case (ECC) if possible, but fallback nicely to RSA for older clients.

Comment: Yeah I just thought they where the same certificate just represented in different formats. Thank you for your input tho!

Answer (score 2):

There are two CA certificates offered on the site you refer to:

[image]

The first one is the RSA certificate with the OU "CloudFlare Origin SSL Certificate Authority". The seconds one is the ECC certificate OU "CloudFlare Origin SSL ECC Certificate Authority".

Looks like you took ECC certificate while you should have taken the RSA certificate.

Comment: Okay yeah thank you, that gets me a "OK" for the `openssl verify` command. I thought they where just different versions of the same certificate (and the wording on Cloudflares site suggests that imo).

Still, my curl command does not accept it? (Both certs (yes the RSA one) are in the proper paths like described above)
`curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain`

Comment: @Moritz: I think I need the actual URL where you think this certificate is installed in order to reproduce the issue with curl. Maybe the server side configuration is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: The actual URL is proxied through Cloudflare, so pinging it from somewhere else will give a Cloudflare IP and a different Cloudflare Edge Certificate (that works)
it's only the local connection that does not work.

When I do `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect example.com:443` it says "verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain", when I do `openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem cert.pem` it says okay...

Here is the output of the "openssl" command: <https://pastebin.com/Fv5JDhmx>
note that the first cert listed by that command is `cert.pem` and the second is the root CA

Comment: @Moritz: Given that it works if `ca.pem` is explicitly given but not when the default trust path is used I can only conclude that the CA certificate is not properly installed in the default trust path __on the clients machine__, no matter what you claim in your question. Note that a root CA should not be added to the certificate chain send by the server like you do. And even if it is added it will be ignored since the root CA must be locally trusted by the client.